# Background Image not appearing in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to follow along with a tutorial to build a small game in JavaScript using libraries but I'm trying to type everything out myself instead of copy/paste etc in order to learn more effectively, whilst changing some aspects. However I'm trying to add a background image into a canvas but when I run it all I see is a blank white screen. I'm not sure if I'm being stupid and missing simple syntax or if it's more complicated. Here is the HTML and the JS file. I have a png image in the assets folder called 'background'.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>1812 Shooter Game</title>
        <link href="normalize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Game File -->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="game.js" />

        <!-- CDN For CreateJS Library -->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js" />


    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="GameCanvas"></canvas>
    </body>

</html>
```

**game.js**

```
var context;
var queue;
var WIDTH = 3072;
var HEIGHT = 1536;
var mouseXPosition;
var mouseYPosition;
var batImage;
var stage;
var animation;
var deathAnimation;
var spriteSheet;
var enemyXPos=100;
var enemyYPos=100;
var enemyXSpeed = 1.5;
var enemyYSpeed = 1.75;
var score = 0;
var scoreText;
var gameTimer;
var gameTime = 0;
var timerText;

window.onload = function() {
    //     Set up the Canvas with Size and height
    var canvas = document.getElementById('GameCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.canvas.width = WIDTH;
    context.canvas.height = HEIGHT;
    stage = new createjs.Stage("GameCanvas");

    //Set up the Asset Queue and load sounds
    queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    queue.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
    queue.on("complete", queueLoaded, this);
    createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["ogg"];

    //Create a load manifest for all assets
    queue.loadManifest([ {
        id: 'backgroundImage', src: 'assets/background.png'},
        //{id: 'crossHair', src: 'assets/crosshair.png'},
        //{id: 'shot', src: 'assets/shot.mp3'},
        //{id: 'background', src: 'assets/countryside.mp3'},
        //{id: 'gameOverSound', src: 'assets/gameOver.mp3'},
        //{id: 'tick', src: 'assets/tick.mp3'},
        //{id: 'deathSound', src: 'assets/die.mp3'},
        //{id: 'batSpritesheet', src: 'assets/batSpritesheet.png'},
        //{id: 'batDeath', src: 'assets/batDeath.png'},
    ]);
    queue.load();

    //Create a timer that updates once per second
    gameTimer = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
}

function queueLoaded(event) {
    // Add background image
    var backgroundImage = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("backgroundImage"))
    stage.addChild(backgroundImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to update the stage any time content changes.

```
var backgroundImage = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("backgroundImage"))
stage.addChild(backgroundImage);
stage.update();
```

You didn't post your `updateTime` method, so I am not sure if it updates your stage for you. Usually in a game/app that is constantly changing, there will be a constant stage update:

```
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", stage);
// OR
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", handleTick);
function handleTick(event) {
    stage.update(event);
}
```

Comment: Sorry where should I add the createjs.on("tick", stage); line? I just added the stage.Update line but still no change

Comment: Sorry, my code was wrong. It should read `createjs.Ticker.on("tick", stage);` ... You can put that in your onload (it should just happen one time). Do you have an online sample? Perhaps something else is going wrong. Do you have any errors in your console?